Can I build android/iphone app using php,html,javascript and inject as iframe and access location?
I want to build a simple app. I know only php,mysql,html,javascript. I will hire somebody to build app wrapper into which I will insert iframe. Would be possible to build app and then just include it as iframe? I need to ask your permission to access location and upload images. Can I access this and send it to iframe?

Yes. There is Webview for Android and IOS. It is embedded browser to display the web content. You can access location and files to upload image with the help of android(java) / IOS (swift) and the rest is via webview display.
